# Write YAML file from python dict containing special characters (asterisk, ampersand, *, &)

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, config, pyyaml

I have a YAML file, that I need to import to python, process it in some way and then export as YAML file again. More precisely I import YAML config file as a dict, generate many files with altering parameters and then write them all as YAML files again.

The problem I facing is that there are parameters with special characters ($, &) before them: e.g. *target_size.

When I'm working with a dict in python, then this parameter is a dictionary value in a string format ('*target_size'). When I'm writing this dict as YAML file formatting get preserved, i.e. '*target_size' is encircled by quotes in resulting YAML file. What I need is just *target_size, same as in the original file.

I've looked pyYaml docs and other resources but didn't found the solution.

Code to write YAML file:

```
    with open(f'{PATH}/base_config.yml', 'w') as outfile:
         yaml.dump(config, outfile, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

[image: original YAML] 
[image: python dict]
[image: resulting file]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unquoted asterisk (`*`) and ampersand (`&`) are special characters in YAML, representing  [aliases and anchors](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/yaml-anchors-960154027.html). These let one portion of a YAML document refer to another portion of a YAML document.

When you deserialize a YAML document into a Python data structure, you lose any information about the anchors and aliases that were present in the original document.

When you serialize a Python data structure to YAML, the `yaml` module will automatically generate anchors and aliases where appropriate to represent self-referential data structures.  For example, given this:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> doc = {'a': {'example': 'this is a test'}}
>>> doc['b'] = doc['a']
>>> print(yaml.safe_dump(doc))
```

We see the following output:

```
a: &id001
  example: this is a test
b: *id001
```

You're not going to be able to preserve these across a deserialization/serialization pipeline using the standard Python `yaml` module.

Comment: Oh, I see, now it is clear. Will try to do the thing the other way. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want that the `pyyaml` Dumper uses aliases and anchors you can execute `Dumper.ignore_aliases = lambda self, data: True` before using the Dumper.